# Accessing website on port of machine in Domain

Tags: port, domain

I have a sharepoint machine called monkeyface in our domain. If I go to any browser and type in `http://monkeyface/` I get the website as planned.

I have a dev site on port 1000. If I open `http://monkeyface:1000/` on any machine other than monkeyface, I do not get a website.

I have also tried the full machine name, and no luck.

Where do I start?

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like a port is blocked. Do you have an internal firewall that could be stopping traffic on port 1000?

Comment: good call. let me check.

Comment: nope :( Tried completely disabling windows and hardware firewall

Comment: also, cannout ping monkeyface:1000

Comment: Can you telnet to monkeyface on port 1000? If you can't do that, then the port is blocked somewhere along the way.

Comment: I should also mention, ping doesn't use ports, so a ping using a port will always fail, it is not a valid test if a port is open. You can see this if you ping google.com and then ping google.com:80. As I mentioned above, use telnet to test TCP connectivity on a specific port.

Comment: Firewall was correct, but it was on the server, not my client machine. Submit the answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a case of a firewall port blocking. Check the firewall on the server to make sure port 1000 is open. Since it is not a port that is normally used, it is probably blocked by default.